# How to run django server from python script without using terminal?

Tags: python, django

Generally a django server is started using python manage.py runserver in the terminal. I want to run the server by running a python script. How to do so?

Comment: that is unrelated to the question

Answer (score 3):

You could just have the Python script execute the command with `os.system`:

```
os.system('python manage.py runserver')
```